# php to javascript and back

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I have a php file that generates some html and do some database queries.
And there is some switch case statement. In one particular case I need to send to the user some dialog. If the user press OK I need to to some db queries and if the user press cancel I do not. So I decided to echo out a JavaScript code snippet which contains a confirm statement.
So how can I send from the JavaScript the result of the confirm message back to php, and decide make a db query or not.

```
<?php 
// some code
switch $_REQUEST['action']
case 'save':
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'if (!confirm("text + variables") ) { ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                           ajax.open("POST",filename.php,true);
                                           ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                           ajax.send("userChoice=false");
                                         }',
     '</script>';
if (!empty($_POST['userChoice'])) {
    echo 'got the variable from javascript!'
    // do some code
}
```

But unfortunately `$_POST['userChoice']` is always empty.
Does anybody know why?

Comment: Where's the HTML that includes `name="userChoice"`?

Comment: Do i need one? I want just pass the value of ajax.send() to the $_POST variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put in the filename without quotes.

Javascript then doesn't know it is a string containing the filename, it thinks it's an object instance called `filename` with a property `php`.

```
ajax.open("POST", "filename.php" ,true);
```

Don't mix PHP and JS this way,... they are totally different languages, serverside, clientside,.

Build your Javascript a way so it works without PHP.

Let then PHP inject some configuration using:

```
<script>
var config = <?php json_encode($phpToJs); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: @cofirazak Can you confirm/verify it doesn't send anything by providing a screenshot of the network console?

Comment: hm. in the console i see the variable, but not in the $_REQUEST variable further in the php file. why so?

Comment: @cofirazak HOW are you supposed to see something? Ajax requests don't generate visible output unless you show it explicitly through HTML (not PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the parameter within the url when calling `ajax.open();`

Example: `filename.php?userChoice=false`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `break;` and `default` in switch statment

Comment: Yeah, but it's only here, in the production file i don't mis them